# Ambiguity in a fully qualified static member variable

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, fully-qualified-naming

In this sample code, there is two sentences showing the same static variable. The first one gives no ambiguity, but the second one does, why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A { static const char a = 'a'; };
struct B : public A { };
struct C : public A { };
struct G : public B, public C { };

int main()
{
    G v;

    cout << G::B::A::a << endl;
    cout << v.B::A::a << endl;
}
```

GCC error (according to some comments, there's no ambiguity in clang):

```
main.cpp:15:18: error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'G'
  cout << v.B::A::a << endl;
```

[Code on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d43d2604247b3c0)

Comment: I know I saw something like this a month or so ago.  I believe it does not know which parent to use in the `v` case.  Trying to find it.

Comment: @barakmanos Precisely, I'm researching the case when I don't need virtual inheritance.

Comment: This compiles successfully with clang.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `struct E : public C` up there?

Comment: @Peregring-lk, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d43d2604247b3c0 is about 20 times easier to read and understand. Most of your example is irrelevant noise that just obscures things.

Comment: EDG accepts it too. Please report a GCC bug (if you can't find an existing one), with the minimal example (not your verbose original). Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I think, your clarified example is worthy an answer.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's just the MCVE that should have been in the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in GCC, as a [GCC maintainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445130/ambiguity-in-a-fully-qualified-static-member-variable#comment62392712_37445130) recommends you report it. However, until it's fixed, you can use a nasty workaround like this:

```
std::cout << static_cast<B &>(v).A::a;
```

The advantage is this will help disambiguate if in a (complex) scenario that there are variables with the same name in one of the base classes.